# JavaScript: getting undefined variable message but variable is defined (I think)

Tags: javascript, function, variables, undefined

I'm relatively new to JavaScript, although I have recently turned a corner. I just wrote this code block to validate an email field that's generated by a CMS, but I'm getting a message that invalidEmailMsg is undefined. I have tried placing the variable declaration inside the function, outside the function, inside the if statement (basically flailing my arms around), but the message persists. Can anyone help? Please and thank you.

```
var email = document.getElementById("trouble-tickets-email");
email.addEventListener("keyup", function() {  
    var invalidEmailMsg = document.forms[1].getElementsByClassName("form-error-msg")[3]; 
    var emailValue = email.value;
    var emailPattern = /.+@.+\..+/;       
    if(emailPattern.test(emailValue) === false) {   
        invalidEmailMsg.css.style("display","block");
        invalidEmailMsg.innerHTML = "custom message";
    }  
});
```

Comment: Does `document.forms[1].getElementsByClassName("form-error-msg")` really returns at least 4 elements?

Comment: Try splitting `document.forms[1].getElementsByClassName("form-error-msg")[3]` into separate variables and confirm each value before assuming the result was valid.

Comment: Also if there's only one form, you should use `document.forms[0]` to get it because arrays are zero-based in JavaScript.

Comment: why not adding an `id` to the element you're trying to select by the following code `document.forms[1].getElementsByClassName("form-error-msg")[3];`

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` return null or empty if nothing match with your request (fourth element with class name form-error-msg in your case) so you cant make `null.css` or `empty.css`;

Comment: Unfortunately, the form was created with a content management system, so I don't know how to access its elements to add IDs to them. That's why I'm grabbing it with that path. And it's the 2nd form on the page, which is why I used the index of 1. I'll try breaking up my variables and see if that helps. Thanks!